# Is it possible to remap windows shortcuts to unix/emacs style?

Tags: windows, emacs, shortcut

I have currently switched to ubuntu at my home computer after being in the windows world for more than a decade. However, I still need to use windows and I'm having problems with the shortcuts for copy/paste/cut/etc.

For example, I would like C-a to do the same as the Home key, instead of "select all".

I would really like to remap these windows shortcuts to unix style.

Is it possible to do such a thing, or is it totally application specific??

(I can't switch to linux at work. saddly =/)

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you are asking to do this within Emacs or outside of Emacs.

Comment: It is outside of emacs in a windows environment.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/XKeymacs it made working in MSVS almost tolerable for me (with few exceptions).

Comment: This is just simply amazing. Just what I was looking for.

Now my vba editor has the flavor of emacs navigation and the basic keystrokes. This will make me infinitely more productive! =DDDD

Put it as an answer and I will accept it.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no native way to do that, as applications generally manage their own keyboard shortcuts (with a few exceptions, like alt-f4). You could certainly experiment, however, with autohotkey - you can write scripts in autohotkey that will remap keyboard presses either globally or per-application. If you really did want pressing ctrl+a to act as if you had pressed Home in any application, it would look like this in an autohotkey script:

```
^a::{Home}
```

To the application, it would appear that you had actually pressed the Home key, because autohotkey would sit between the OS and the application, remapping your key presses. (As I said, if you only wanted this to occur in certain applications, you can also specify that using "#IfWinActive". For more details, see the [documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

Comment: Never heard of autohotkey. It looks like it would solve my problem with some work. I will definitely look at this when I get home =).

Thanks.